# Kibana metric to sum all num values from last date value

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, metrics

new to Elastic, using Elastic cloud.
I have documents including two relevant fields: num_value, date.
I want to display a metric in Kibana dashboard that sums all num_value values from last date value.
Should be pretty straight forward query but I don't know how to approach this.
I tried using this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html and bodybuilder but didn't get even remotely close.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is using bucket sort with date histogram.